# Split function working weird?

Tags: string, scala

This is my input string and am trying to split in Scala. i find that there seems to be some fundamental difference in the way I understood split or this is not working according to my input. My input had 0,"","" as last three chars. When on split, the output stops with 0 and last two blank characters in the input string "" and "", are ignored.

This is my regular exp

```
val lines = "5;;ABCDEF;GHIJK;;DEC;XXXX;;;;;;YYYY;ZZZZZ;XXXXXXX ;4;YYYY;;;;;;;;;0**;;;**"    

val parsedArray = lines.map(_.split("\\;"))

Array[java.lang.String] = Array(5, "", ABCDEF, GHIJK, "", DEC, XXXX, "", "", "", "", "", YYYY, ZZZZZ, XXXXXXX, 4, YYYY, "", "", "", "", "", "", "", **"", 0)**
```

Can you sense something ?

Comment: what regex are you using as split expression?

Comment: You need to pass a negative number as second parameter (limit). Read the documentation.

Comment: I have added the split reg-ex.What does the number signify - Link for `split()` API?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String, int)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String,%20int%29):

> If n is non-positive then the pattern will be applied as many times as
>   possible and the array can have any length. If n is zero then the
>   pattern will be applied as many times as possible, the array can have
>   any length, and trailing empty strings will be discarded.